# signalR chat with db mvc4

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4, chat, message, signalr

how to set up the db to connect two users chats?  Each profile has an inbox and when you click on on of the chats it brings up the entire history of chat with that person. Saving the chats and the usernames are not a problem but linking two users together so the right chat is retrieved is giving the problem. Any tutorials about? First time coding a messaging system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to save the user id and the connection id to your database as well as saving the messages that are sent in that chat. When you load the users inbox, you can load their past chats from the database with their chat id and the user they were chatting with. When they click on one of them you can load their chat history using the chat id and/or user id doing something like this (haven't tested, just a mock up):

```
public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
{
    string chatID =  Context.ConnectionId; 
    string history = GetHistory(chatID);

    Clients.Caller.chatHistory(history);
    //you'll need to create a chatHistory handler on the client side.   
}

private string GetHistory(string chatID)
{
    return dbcontext.GetChatHistory(chatID);
}
```